# Converting Map(Key, List) to Map(ListValue, Key) in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, group-by

I have a following map:

```
Map("uniquePersonId1" -> List("subaru", "honda"), 
 "uniquePersonId2" -> List("honda", "toyota"))
```

Is there a way in scala by which I can convert the map above to

```
Map("subaru" -> List("uniquePersonId1"),
    "honda" -> List("uniquePersonId1", "uniquePersonId2"),
    "toyota" -> List("uniquePersonId2"))
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
scala> val m = Map("uniquePersonId1" -> List("subaru", "honda"), 
                   "uniquePersonId2" -> List("honda", "toyota"))

scala> m flatten { case(k, vs) => vs map ((_, k)) } groupBy (_._1) mapValues { _ map (_._2) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]] = 
     Map(subaru -> List(uniquePersonId1), 
         toyota -> List(uniquePersonId2), 
         honda -> List(uniquePersonId1, uniquePersonId2))
```

And another solution with `fold`:

```
m.foldLeft(Map[String, List[String]]().withDefaultValue(Nil)) { 
    case(r, (k, vs)) => vs.foldLeft(r){ (u, v) => u.updated(v, k::u(v)) } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done in the following way:

```
var maps = Map("uniquePersonId1" -> List("subaru", "honda"), 
"uniquePersonId2" -> List("honda", "toyota"))

class CarToId(c:String, i:String) {
    var car:String = c
    var id:String = i
}

var mapping = maps.flatMap(p => p._2.map(i => new CarToId(i, p._1)))
var result = mapping.groupBy(i => i.car).mapValues(c => c.map(y => y.id))
```

If you guys happen to know a better way to do, please let me know.

Comment: You can just use `case class CarToId(car:String, id:String)` - no need for extra member variables

Answer (score 0):

Just try to provide another seemingly explicit way without extra class imported

```
val originalMap =
    Map(
        "uniquePersonId1" -> List("subaru", "honda"),
        "uniquePersonId2" -> List("honda", "toyota")
    )

// k1 -> List(A, B) change to  List(A -> k1, B -> k1)
val intermediateList = originalMap.map {
    case (key, strList) => strList.map(_ -> key)
}.toList.flatten

/*
    intermediateList: List[(String, String)] = List((subaru,uniquePersonId1), (honda,uniquePersonId1), (honda,uniquePersonId2), (toyota,uniquePersonId2))
*/
val finalResult = intermediateList.foldLeft(Map[String, List[String]]())({
    case (acc, (k1, v1)) => {
        // if the key already exists, replace the value with new one
        acc + {
            k1 -> {
                acc.find(_._1 == k1).map { matched =>
                    v1 :: matched._2
                }.getOrElse {
                    (v1 :: Nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

// Map(subaru -> List(uniquePersonId1), honda -> List(uniquePersonId2, uniquePersonId1), toyota -> List(uniquePersonId2))
println(finalResult)
```